# Why does no 3 by 3 matrix have a nullspace that equals its column space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix. Then
$\dim Null(A) + \dim Col(A) = n.$

Since the null space and the column spaces are equal their dim must be equal.

$r + r = n.$ (Since $n = 3$ in the problem, $r = \frac 32$, hence the it is not possible).

I constructed a matrix: $A=  \pmatrix{ 1& 1 &1\\ 1& 1& 1\\ -2& -2& -2}$ and$ X = \pmatrix{ -1\\ -1 \\2}$
Here $AX= 0.$ The column space of $A = \pmatrix { 1 \\ 1\\ -2}$ and the $X = \pmatrix {-1\\ -1\\ 2}$ and both are equal.

I think I have missed some important theory behind. Plz help.

Ref: 1. pg: 142, prb: 27, gilbert strang, introduction to linear algebra 
     2. http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/geoffp/lm-ss/amlect12.pdf

Comment: Because the space generated by {X} does not equal Null($A$)

Answer (score 3):

$Y=\pmatrix{1\\ -1\\ 0}$ is also in the null space of $A$, but it is linearly independent of $X$.

Comment: Thanks.  It  makes sense to me now. The null space is 2 dim and column space is 1 dimension in the example.

Answer (score 0):

By the identity that you give at the beginning of the question, we know that the dimension of $A$’s null space must be $3-1=2$, so it’s impossible for the single vector $X$ to span it. You’ve shown that the column space of $A$ is a subset of its null space, but not that they are equal.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Could you please give further more explanation. I have difficulty in interpreting -- " It is impossible for a single vector is span it " & " column space of AA is a subset of its null space, but not that they are equal. "

Comment: @ChitturiRatnakar How is the dimension of a vector space defined?

Comment: Dimensions of a vectors spaces is the number of vectors required to define the space i.e No of vectors in the basis of that vector field.

Comment: Thanks @amd. It make sense to me know. What I have given here is a subset of the Null space of A. I appreciate your approach.

Comment: $ Null (A) = \pmatrix{ -1& -1 \\ 1& 0 \\ 0& 1& }$.  $X = \pmatrix{ -1 \\  -1 \\ 2 }   = 2 *  \pmatrix{ -1 \\  0 \\ 1 } - \pmatrix{ -1 \\  1 \\ 0 }  $

Answer (score 0):

The column space of A is line in 3 dimension. Its null space is all linear combinations of its two special solutions, which is R2 space in R3.

You miss the point that Null(A) should have two special solutions, instead of one.